# how to fetch last line data from this xml by using xslt

Tags: xslt

trying to get last from the tag if data of last line is equal to personal means then need to populate as 1100 else what ever data presented that it should to be populated
here is my below xml:

```
    <tag>
    <name>20K</name>
    <value>540211000000100155001
    0100155XXXXXX
    0100156XXXXX
    0100157XXXXXXX
    0100159XXXXXXXX
    personal</value>
</tag>
```

how to use a logic in xslt can any one guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. Here is a short and simple way to do this in XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/value">
     "<xsl:sequence select="tokenize(., '(&#xD;)?&#xA;')[last()]"/>"
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<tag>
    <name>20K</name>
    <value>540211000000100155001
    0100155XXXXXX
    0100156XXXXX
    0100157XXXXXXX
    0100159XXXXXXXX
    personal</value>
</tag>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
"    personal"
```

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="value" name="skipLines">
   <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xA;'))">
        "<xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>"
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:call-template name="skipLines">
         <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
             "substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the same XML document (above), again the same correct result is produced**:

```
"    personal"
```

Comment: +1 Although `(&#xD;)?` shouldn't be needed, since XML parsers will normalize CR+LF characters into LF.  You should be able to just tokenize on `&#xA;`.

Comment: @MadsHansen: Yes, I know very well what *should* be the text according to spec, however in practice an `XmlReader` may be configured to preserve the `&#xD`. For example, in .NET, `XmlTextReader.Normalization` may be set to false.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that .NET had that option. Conformant XML parsers *MUST* normalize into a single `#xA;`. http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-line-ends

Answer (score -2):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tag">
  <xsl:if test="contains(value/text(),"personal")">
    do stuff ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
just for inspiration :)
```